# not a procedure; expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments given: #<void> in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I got it print sub (A 3333) (A 4444), but I can't figure out to print out both
sub (A 3333) (A 4444)
add (R 0) (R 1)

```
(define tree '("S" ( ("-"("A" 3333 )("A" 4444))) ("W" (("+" ("R" 0) ("R" 1))))))

(define (OperandNode on)
    (display on))

(define (TwoOperandNode x)
    (car x)
    (if(equal? (car x) "-")
       ((display "sub")
        (OperandNode (cadr x))
        (OperandNode (caddr x)))))

(TwoOperandNode (caadr tree))

(define (WhileNode h)
    (car h)
    (if(equal? (car h) "+")
       ((display "add")
        (WhileNode (cadr h))
        (WhileNode (caddr h)))))

(WhileNode (caaadr tree))
```

Comment: Parentheses are not used for grouping. And since you're using Racket, let DrRacket indent your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You know that for the following form:

```
(+ 1 2)
```

The parts are evaluated, eg. `+` gets evaluated ta procedure `#<procedure:+>` and the numbers get evaluated to themselves. Then Scheme applies it and gets the result `3`. Now look at what you have done in `WhileNode`:

```
((display "add") (WhileNode (cadr h)) (WhileNode (caddr h))) ; ==
(#<void> ...) ; throws error
```

So the parts get evaluated here to. However the problem is that the expression in operator position, `(display "add")`, returns `#<void>`. It doesn't know how to continue from this. In Java the same code would look like this:

```
System.out.println("add")(WhileNode(cadr(h)), WhileNode(caddr(h)));
```

In Scheme its perfectly natural to have expressions in operator position, but it must evaluate to a procedure:

```
(define (abs-proc x)
  (if (positive? x) 
      values
      -))

((abs-proc -5) -5) ; ==
(- -5)             ; ==
; ==> 5

((abs-proc 3) 3) ; ==
(values 3)       ; ==
; ==> 3
```